# Howto hide UIPopoverController when UIWebView plays a fullscreen youtube movie?

Tags: ios, uiwebview, youtube

Please see the picture. After pressing the fullscreen button, the `webview` maximizes *behind* the `UIPopover`.

[image: http://cl.ly/2V1r0i2w3v3z0z2b1X1n]

I tried to look out for `MPMoviePlayerDidEnterFullscreenNotification`, no luck.

I really don't want to ship my own `UIPopoverController` but this is my only `"solution"` at the moment. Using anything other than `UIWebView` is also not an option, as I am displaying YouTube-Movies.

**Edit:** I use a `UIWebView`, so there is no way to access the views/classes that are used internally.

Comment: I suspect this is a UIWebView bug.

Comment: I'm seeing the exact same behavior. Same conditions on my side, trying to display a YouTube movie within a UIWebView, and then the full screen version shows up behind the popover controller. Did you ever figure out a workaround for this?

Comment: I know this is a pretty old post. Did you find a solution for this? I have done some workaround for this sometime back. It was something like, checking the MPMoviePlayerDidEnterFullscreenNotification and dismissing UIPopover in that. What was the issue you were facing when this happened?

Comment: I ended up not using popovers for that, so worked around the issue. it's also quite some time, maybe Apple has fixed this since.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9088751/1008736) you can listen for `UIMoviePlayerControllerDidEnterFullscreenNotification`

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(youTubeStarted:) name:@"UIMoviePlayerControllerDidEnterFullscreenNotification" object:nil];
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(youTubeFinished:) name:@"UIMoviePlayerControllerDidExitFullscreenNotification" object:nil];
```

Comment: @steipete the other alternative is to use KVO on the UIApplication's window stack. When a window is added to that stack, hide your popover.